# Output HTML Canvas (w/ Fabric.js) to PDF in Specified Size

Tags: html, pdf, canvas, fabricjs, jspdf

I have an HTML canvas that utilizes Fabric.js. The canvas is used to create text that will ultimately be engraved on a plaque. I need to be able to generate a pdf from the canvas that is sized to the necessary dimensions.

I have been messing around with jsPDF, and can easily generate the PDF. The problem is outputting a document that is the dimensions I need. Happy to try any other libraries that may help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check PDFlib.
Here is an exemple:https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/graphics/starter-svg/